# Dame dinero "para que compre leche" o "para comprar leche"?

Tags: gramática

Ayer estudié que se utiliza "para + infinitivo" cuando los sujetos son iguales, por ejemplo:

> (yo) Como solo fruta para (yo) ayunar

Mientras que se utiliza "para que + subjuntivo" cuando los sujetos son diferentes, por lo tanto la frase:

> (tú) Dame dinero para que (yo) compre leche

tendría que ser correcta.

Pero en esta frase me parece también correcto utilizar el "para + infinitivo" y decir:

> Dame dinero para comprar leche

¿Se puede decir o es un error?

Comment: Creo que ambas oraciones son correctas, pero no puedo ofrecer ninguna referencia ahora mismo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las dos frases:

> (tú) Dame dinero para que (yo) compre leche
>
> Dame dinero para comprar leche

son correctas y equivalentes. Lo que comentas sobre el "**para que + subjuntivo**" cuando los subjetos son diferentes también es cierto, pero se aplica para no confundirse con usar otro tiempo verbal cuando hay
un cambio de sujeto.

Además hay una sutil diferencia entre las dos frases: en la primera usas **para que** y en la segunda, usas solo **para**. Esta es la diferencia fundamental que permite usar el subjuntivo.

Puedes echar un vistazo a [este ejercicio](http://palabraspormadrid.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/para-para-que.html) para comprobarlo.

Comment: *que* no siempre activa el subjuntivo. Por ejemplo *dale el dinero y ojalá compre leche / dale el dinero para ojalá comprar leche.*

Comment: @Ustanak gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 4):

Ambas son correctas. He aquí por qué:

La RAE define esta clase de oraciones como *oraciones finales concertadas*<sup>1</sup>. En estos casos, la subordinada puede ir en infinitivo cuando hay una correferencia de sujetos, esto es, cuando el sujeto de ambas partes es el mismo. Ahora bien, esta correferencia puede darse tanto entre sujetos gramaticales como entre el sujeto de la subordinada y el complemento directo o indirecto de la principal, con la diferencia de que mientras que la correferencia estricta entre sujetos activos exige que el verbo de la subordinada esté en infinitivo, este otro tipo de correferencia admite verbos tanto personales como impersonales. Combinando ambas variables, se obtienen seis combinaciones posibles:

> 1. CORREFERENCIA «SUJETO-SUJETO»
>    a) Oración de infinitivo: "Elena lo llamó para disculparse".⇒ El sujeto del verbo principal (*Elena*) es correferente con el sujeto tácito del infinitivo *disculparse*.
>    b) Oración de verbo finito o en forma personal: "El plomero fue contratado para que arreglara la calefacción de todo el edificio". ⇒ El sujeto del verbo principal (*el plomero*) es correferente con el sujeto tácito del verbo subordinado *arreglara*.
> 2. CORREFERENCIA «COMPLEMENTO DIRECTO-SUJETO»
>    a) Oración de infinitivo: "La llamaron para impartir un curso de maestría". ⇒ El complemento directo del verbo principal (*la*) es correferente con el sujeto tácito del infinitivo *impartir*.
>    b) Oración de verbo finito o en forma personal: "La llamaron para que impartiera un curso de maestría". ⇒ El complemento directo del verbo principal (*la*) es correferente con el sujeto tácito del verbo subordinado *impartiera*.
> 3. CORREFERENCIA «COMPLEMENTO INDIRECTO-SUJETO»
>    a) Oración de infinitivo: "Le hicieron una sustanciosa oferta para cambiar de empresa". ⇒ El complemento indirecto del verbo principal (*le*) es correferente con el sujeto tácito del infinitivo *cambiar.*
>    b) Oración de verbo finito o en forma personal: "Dales unas monedas para que se compren un helado". ⇒ El complemento indirecto del verbo principal (*les*) es correferente con el sujeto tácito del verbo subordinado compren.
>
> [Nueva gramática](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bnXsbIrkgRcFRyH,)

En este caso, se tiene una correferencia de tercer tipo: **correferencia complemento indirecto (*me*) -sujeto (*yo*)**. Como se puede ver en los dos ejemplos de este tipo citados arriba, son igual de válidas las oraciones con infinitivo ("para cambiar de empresa") como con subjuntivo ("para que se compren un helado"). Al ser ambas formas válidas, si el sujeto no se especifica el significado es ambiguo. Considérese una oración similar al ejemplo pero algo más indeterminada:

> Dame dinero para salir del país ⇒ ¿Quién va a salir del país, el que recibe el dinero o el que lo da?
>
> Dame dinero para que salga del país ⇒ Misma ambigüedad, en este caso provocada porque la primera y tercera persona del singular coinciden para el presente de subjuntivo. ¿Quién va a salir del país, el que recibe el dinero o una tercera persona no mencionada?

Obsérvese cómo esta ambigüedad no surge con oraciones que solo admiten una forma:

> Quiero salir del país ⇒ El sujeto solo puede ser el hablante.
> Quiero que salga del país ⇒ El sujeto solo puede ser una tercera persona.

Ello también determina que "Quiero salir tú del país" y "Quiero que salga yo del país" sean ambas incorrectas, mientras que "Dame dinero para que yo compre leche" y "Dame dinero para que él compre leche" son ambas válidas.

Para terminar de aclarar que las formas con subjuntivo e infinitivo son ambas correctas, cito un ejemplo de la RAE similar a este:

> En *Le dio dinero para que comprara unos tazones* (Montero, M., Capitán), (...) se admitiría ... *para comprar unos tazones*.

---

<sup>1: "Finales" expresa que la subordinada especifica la finalidad de la acción descrita en la principal, y "Concertadas" expresa que los sujetos gramaticales o lógicos de ambas se refieren a la misma entidad. Para más información, ver §46.9 de la [Nueva gramática de la lengua española](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi). Se puede acceder a la sección introduciendo "46.9" en el cuadro de búsquedas.</sup>